# Set ALL Values of PostgreSQL column to X

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

I have a PostgreSQL database table with same sample data whose schema is shown below.

```
| UserId | XP | Level |
-----------------------
| 123456 | 55 | 12    |
| 134156 | 45 | 4     |
| 526083 | 39 | 5     |
| 115646 | 12 | 1     |
```

I want to set every value in the `XP` and `Level` column to 1. How would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to reset every value in the `XP` and `Level` column back to `1`.

You seem to be looking for a simple `update` query:

```
update mytable set xp = 1, level = 1
```